# Updating a website and accessing it through its IP address

Tags: powershell, ssh, backend, webserver, updating

I have to make some updates on a website. I know front-end but nothing of back-end. I have been given the host server's IP address, and the website username and password; yes, it's a password protected website.
Now I don't know how to advance from here. How to access the website and where are those password credentials needed? How to gain access to its files and update them or change them is needed?

I tried to access the website using ssh protocol through windows PowerShell in VS Code and did get the access to the corresponding directories. I can change between folders and can see the file names. But now I am not able to download them for an updating session and neither do I know how to delete those old ones and upload new files in their places. I searched the web but couldn't get any valuable output. So can someone guide me through how to do it?! Assume myself to be a 5th grader. Thanks!